# how to get those selected file's from hardisk inside file tag and pass it into another php function

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, database

here i'am trying to do is extract some not null values from database and attach images to it 
php code to get value is

```
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = '';
            $dbname = "question_collection";
            $conn = " ";

            $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

            if($conn->connect_error) 
            {
                die('Could not connect: '.$conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "select * from question_detail where image_name is NOT NULL";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);


            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                echo "<table>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th>Questions</th>";
                        echo "<th>Image Name</th>";
                        echo "<th>Select image</th>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    { 
                        echo "<tr>";
                            $question_name=$row['questions'];
                            $image_name=$row['image_name'];
                            $id=$row['question_id'];
                            echo "<td>".$question_name."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$image."</td>";
                            echo "<td> <input type='file' name='file'> </td>";
                            $image_files[$id] = $image;                                
                        echo "</tr>";

                    }
                echo "</table>";
            }                 
     ?>
```

now after it displayed the values i have added a button below this php code

```
   <input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
```

what i want is after selecting images when user click this button then a function for ex upload_image() will execute and passing i need 3 items inside this function from above php code 
1- $image_name
2- $id
3- file's that are selected from harddisk

and let suppose the table formed by the  initial value's selected from database contains 3 row's and user select's image's for all three of them then he pressed the upload button
now the button should pick all three of these images and their id's and there name's and pass it into new function that contains php code to upload file into database.

Comment: Please help me through it , i have been stuck for days

Comment: You'll need to have that `<input>` inside of a `<form>`. From here you'll need to `POST` the data to another PHP page (as the `<form>` itself is merely client-side HTML). This PHP page would then process the `$_POST` information that was passed to it, and handle things from there.

Comment: hello , thank you for the reply, 
i did put <input> inside a <form> but the main thing is how to pass all 3 image file at once into the next page , the id's assigned to the <file> is same for all of three 
because it's inside a while loop
can you help me how m i gonna save those image's into an array and then further process it into the database

Answer (score 1):

Must be in a FORM and target the type file using this.

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
varfile = $('#id')[0].files[0];

ajax/others here . . . .
});
```

handlesRequest.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
$path = '../assets/files/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$supp_file = array(
    'name' => $_FILES['file']['name'],
    'path' => $path
);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '../../assets/files/' . 
$_FILES['file']['name']);
}
```

It's in you how will you implement this in your code.

If you want to upload with multiple files check this: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

```
$("#file").on("change", function(e){
     var file = e.target.files[0];
     var blobs = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i){
         blobs.push($(this).get(0).files[i]);
     }
     console.log(blobs);
});
```

Comment: thank you for the reply 
i wanna know how am i gonna get multiple file's onto the next page mentioned in <form>

Comment: You can perform multiple file when selecting and pressing Ctrl or Shift key and adding multiple attribute in your <input> tag. @Manishsaini

Comment: i'm not asking how to select multiple file's the question is how to get all those selected multiple file into next .php page by <form> and loop through each of the file 
@jEIZART

Comment: I added some code snippet in my answer. Please check if thats the solution you want. @Manishsaini